# What's a word for a doppelgänger only in one's shlemazlut?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a friend who has exactly the same accidents, injuries, mess ups, failings, etc., as I but I can't find a word in English (or otherwise) for it. Physically, we're opposite as night and day. But when something goes wrong, I can match story for story.

Comment: You could coin _doppelschlimazel_.

Comment: Funnily enough, if you analyse the etymology of **sympathy**, it means *suffering together*...

Comment: Doubtful you'll find anything that specific in the English language without using a hyphenated word. *Injury-clone* or *mishap-twin* come to mind. Add some alliteration for *peril-pair* or *disaster-double*.

Comment: Although the intention of the question is clear, I have no idea what a *shlemazlu* is.

Comment: For a hyphenated term, perhaps you are *victims-in-arms*. (But none of these phrases are objectively common.)

Comment: Instead of being "separated at birth," you two could claim to be "separated at the scene of the accident."

Comment: Maybe you should look to Yiddish (High German) for your answer since both of the words you use to define it are loan words and not truly English. I don't know what "shlemazlut" means, but I surmise it refers to the shenanigans of a "schlimazl," and I do know that in Yiddish, a schlimazl's counterpart is a "schlemiel." Whether "schlemiel" covers that meaning, I have no idea because I'm not Jewish and my knowledge of the usage of Yiddish terminology is cursory.

Comment: I think shlemazlut (pl) is 'that which is not mazal' ie. unfortunate experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the absolutely-not-English word "shlemazlut" is derived from the Yiddish word "schlemazel" to mean the foolery of such a fool as a "schlemazel," then the word you're probably looking for is "***schlemiel***."

In Yiddish, the counterpart of a "schlemazel" is a "schlemiel." They aren't identical twins but instead are two very different fools, two very different fools engaged in the same foolery and two very different fools who come together in a complementary fashion as a dyad such that in their ongoing foolery, the "schlemiel" becomes the one who spills the soup and the "schlemazel" becomes the one who slips on it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel

Answer (score 0):

I use the term "mirrors" when it comes to person who exhibit similar thoughts "whoa they completed my sentence..."

also, is your ask neologistic too? leaving aside your tag of "single-word-requests":
The thought "quantum entanglement" comes to my mind, and hence I posted this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/503894/noun-for-particles-that-are-quantum-ly-entangled

so until that is answered ... "he/she is my quangler / quantum-mate / quantum entangler" :p

Edit: as per answer there, "entangled" can be a word that will connote the meaning you want to convey when the audience is bit sciency

Answer (score 0):

**Partner in misfortune** or a broader synonym [fellow-sufferer](https://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/fellow-sufferer#resultsen) could fit there.

I assume the shlemazlut are the misfortunate incidents that happen to the [schlemozel](https://jel.jewish-languages.org/words/1404).
Here's a usage [example](https://www.independent.co.uk/environment/skate-on-thin-ice-5350283.html) from the Independent (UK).

> The skate's partner in misfortune is the angel shark, also known as
>   the monkfish.

Amos Oz's [*A tale of love and darkness*](https://books.google.de/books?id=qCtBgOEYmCMC&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=often+each+sees+in+the+other+not+a+partner+in+misfortune+but&source=bl&ots=SZqlyxRC8t&sig=ACfU3U1J2jU7AMhWXkIudlfPyc5UCfWr0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSgNbs1ODkAhWEYVAKHYRZAw4Q6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=often%20each%20sees%20in%20the%20other%20not%20a%20partner%20in%20misfortune%20but&f=false) also uses the phrase. It's the English translation of the Hebrew, which made me wonder if the original also used some phrase with mazal:

> Often each sees in the other not a partner in misfortune but in fact
>   the image of their common oppressor.